# Formatting set_fact variable

Tags: dictionary, join, ansible

I need to have all the userid in a single variable, all separated by \n.
Code is as below.

```
  - name: Retrieve the user id and instance
    shell: ls -l {{item}} | grep -v total| awk '{print $3}'
    register: find_result_userid
    with_items:
     - /tmp/log/logs/log1
     - /tmp/log/logs/log2
     - /tmp/log/logs/log3


  - name: Combine all userid
    set_fact:
     server_names: "{{ find_result_userid.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}"
```

The output is as below.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "server_names": [
            [
                "root",
                "root",
                "root"
            ],
            [
                "root",
                "root",
                "root"
            ],
            [
                "root",
                "root",
                "root"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

I need something like below: i.e all ids separated by a line in a single variable.

```
 "server_names": [
            [
                "root",
                "root",
                "root",
                "root",
                "root",
                "root",
                "root",
                "root",
                "root"
            ]
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[flatten](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#list-filters) the lists

```
- set_fact:
    server_names: "{{ server_names|flatten }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of items you are iterating with is static, I would guess, that you can use the + operator to append the your results

```
- name: Combine all userid
    set_fact:
     server_names: "{{ find_result_userid.results[0].stdout_lines + find_result_userid.results[1].stdout_lines + find_result_userid.results[2].stdout_lines}}"
```

Otherwise if it is not static, I think Vladimir Botkas answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Combining with what Vladmir Botka suggested, to get result in a single task.

```
  - name: Combine all userid
    set_fact:
      server_names: "{{ find_result_userid.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list | flatten }}"
```