# how to get the correct json format

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

I'm running a task on multiple hosts with register and need the same json output format regardless if the task is executed on one host or multiple.

```
- name: Retrieve Software information
  win_get_software:
  register: facts_software
- name: set fact
  set_fact:
  software_facts: "{{ facts_software.List }}"
```

The module win_get_softare return json data.

The above example overwrites software_facts with the last host data which is unusable.

```
- name: Retrieve Software information
  win_get_software:
  register: facts_software
- name: set fact
  set_fact:
  software_facts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, facts_software') | map(attribute='List') | list }}"
  run_once: yes
  delegate_to: 192.168.1.20
  delegate_facts: true
```

The above example correctly set the variable but as a list which outputs the following json format:

```
[
[
    {
        "TEST-VM": [
            {
                "ADSPath": "WinNT://DOMAIN/TEST-VM/TestAdmin",
                "Class": "User",
                "Domain": "DOMAIN",
                "IsLocal": true,
                "Name": "TestAdmin"
            }
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "TEST2-VM": [
            {
                "ADSPath": "WinNT://DOMAIN/TEST2-VM/TestAdmin",
                "Class": "User",
                "Domain": "DOMAIN",
                "IsLocal": true,
                "Name": "TestAdmin"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

]

I need the following output:

```
[
{
    "TEST-VM": [
        {
                "ADSPath": "WinNT://DOMAIN/TEST-VM/TestAdmin",
                "Class": "User",
                "Domain": "DOMAIN",
                "IsLocal": true,
                "Name": "TestAdmin"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "TEST2-VM": [
        {
                "ADSPath": "WinNT://DOMAIN/TEST2-VM/TestAdmin",
                "Class": "User",
                "Domain": "DOMAIN",
                "IsLocal": true,
                "Name": "TestAdmin"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Does anybody know how I can format the result correctly when dealing with a list?

Comment: what is the difference between the  output and expected output?

Comment: @Asha It's pretty clear if you look at the two outputs

Comment: @Asha: The first output is a list of lists of hashmaps, The expected is a list of hashmaps. @Nico: Please show the structure of the `fact_software` variable with its `List` member that is "unusable".

Comment: I had a similar issue, please check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886502/formatting-set-fact-variable

Comment: @Zeitounator I have x number of hosts with the following original output:
{
    "facts_software": {
        "List": {
            "TEST-VM": {
                "osVersion": "Windows Server 2012R2"
            }
        }, 
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false
    }
}

I'm trying to aggregate "List" for all hosts so that the output looks like this:

{
    "TEST-VM": {
        "osVersion": "Windows Server 2012R2"
    },
    "TEST2-VM": {
        "osVersion": "Windows Server 2012R2"
    }
}

Comment: @Asha flatten filter did not work. Same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by the following tasks:

`- name: set fact
  set_fact:
  software_facts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, facts_software') | map(attribute='List') | list }}"
  run_once: yes
  delegate_to: 192.168.1.20
  delegate_facts: true`

`- name: Reset variable of type hash
  set_fact: 
    combined: {}
- name: Combine items in list
  set_fact:
    combined: "{{ combined | combine(item) }}"
  loop: "{{ software_facts }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "Host {{ my_idx + 1 }} variable was added to list"
    index_var: my_idx`

It's not pretty but it does the job.

Comment: You can use the `default` filter (i.e. `{{ combined | default({}) | combine(item) }}`) to save one unnecessary `set_fact`. Moreover I'm almost sure the following would do the job in one go `{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) | list | json_query('[].fa cts_software.List[]') }}`

Comment: @Zeitounator The last query did not work. Thanks for the try though. Thanks for the tip on default :)

Comment: @Zeitounator Only setting the default() filter without set_fact first does not reset the variable. I run the task multiple times and need the combined variable to reset each time. But now I know about the default filter :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below, not tested though. Add run once, delegate etc

```
- name: Final result
  set_fact:
    result: "{{ result | default({}) + item[0] }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ software_facts }}"
- name: Debug
   debug:
     msg: "{{ result }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but result was: "result": "{} + E"

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if the with items loop run twice. Changes: removed [0] in with_items variable, in result addition, removed {{}}